# How to take player to the lose scene when timer finishes and does not kill enough enemies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game where the player needs to kill a specific number of enemies before the timer runs out. If the player does not kill the number of enemies that he is intended to do so and the timer runs out he will be taken to the lose scene.  My problem is that even if the timer runs out and does not kill the required number of enemies he is not taken to the lose scene. How can I resolve this?

EnemySpawner script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour {


[SerializeField] GameObject EnemyPreFab;
[SerializeField] int MaxEnemies = 30;
[SerializeField] float EnemySpawnTime = 1.00001f;
[SerializeField] GameObject FirstWaypoint;
int  CurrentNumOfEnemies = 0;
int EnemiesToNextLevel = 7;
int KilledEnemies = 0;
public LevelManager myLevelManager;
public static EnemySpawner Instance = null;
int timesEnemyHit;


IEnumerator SpawningEnemies()
{
    while(CurrentNumOfEnemies <= MaxEnemies)
    {
        GameObject Enemy = Instantiate(EnemyPreFab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(EnemySpawnTime);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    if (Instance == null)
        Instance = this;
    StartCoroutine(SpawningEnemies());
    timesEnemyHit = 0;
    if (this.gameObject.tag == "EnemyHit")
    {
        CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
    }


}

public void OnEnemyDeath()
{
   /*  CurrentNumOfEnemies--;
     if (CurrentNumOfEnemies < 5)
     {
         // You killed everyone, change scene: 
         LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
     }
     */

   /* KilledEnemies++;
    if (KilledEnemies >= EnemiesToNextLevel)
    {
        LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
    }
    */

    if(Time.timer == 0.0f && KilledEnemies != EnemiesToNextLevel)
    {
        LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    }


    }



}
```

Timer script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
 {
public Text TimerText;
public float MainTime;
public static float timer;
public  bool CanCount = true;
public  bool OnlyOnce = false;

void Start()
{
    timer = MainTime; //Timer is gonna be equal to what we set MainTime in the inspector 
}

void Update()
{
    if (timer >= 0.0f && CanCount)
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;//The timer will count down in delta time based on the seconds we have 
        TimerText.text = timer.ToString("F");//Converting Timer into a string value 
    }

    //This means that when the timer reaches zero and OnlyOnce is equal to false 
    else if (timer <= 0.0f && !OnlyOnce) //If the timer goes below 0 and OnlyOnce is not equal to flase 
    {

        CanCount = false; //CanCount is equal to false so we are not counting down anymore since it's not greater than zero and we can't count anymore
        OnlyOnce = true; //This is goning to be done once when it reaches it 
        TimerText.text = "0.00"; //Setting the UI to 0 
        timer = 0.0f; //Setting the timer to 0
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: where are you getting the Time.timer, if i were you when it reaches to 0 i would set a boolean to true and ask for that instead of asking for a "0.0f" equality

Comment: Im getting Timer.time from the Timer script but I dont think I am accessing it

Comment: So add a variable : bool timeIsZero = true; and say if(timeisZero && KilledEnemies != EnemiesToNextLevel){LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");{ ?

Comment: Change it to a boolean, when it reaches 0 or lower flag that boolean as true and ask for that static boolean check if that works. Exactly what you wrote above. timeIsZero should be in the EnemySpawner class, and should be modified by the Update function

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly. In the OnEnemyDeath() function I put : if(timeisZero && KilledEnemies != EnemiesToNextLevel){timeisZero = true;
LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");{ and  then I just call OnEnemyDeath() in the Update function ?

Comment: How will it know that it reached 0 ? Do you think you code it for me cause i am not sure  if I am following on what you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code structure: Your enemyspawner can have EnemyKilled and EnemiesToNextLevel variables as public variables. And, you can use Instance variable of EnemySpawner inside timer script.

### New EnemySpawner.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour {


[SerializeField] GameObject EnemyPreFab;
[SerializeField] int MaxEnemies = 30;
[SerializeField] float EnemySpawnTime = 1.00001f;
[SerializeField] GameObject FirstWaypoint;
int  CurrentNumOfEnemies = 0;
public int EnemiesToNextLevel = 7;
public int KilledEnemies = 0;
public LevelManager myLevelManager;
public static EnemySpawner Instance = null;
int timesEnemyHit;


IEnumerator SpawningEnemies()
{
while(CurrentNumOfEnemies <= MaxEnemies)
{
    GameObject Enemy = Instantiate(EnemyPreFab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(EnemySpawnTime);
}
}

void Start()
{
if (Instance == null)
    Instance = this;
StartCoroutine(SpawningEnemies());
timesEnemyHit = 0;
if (this.gameObject.tag == "EnemyHit")
{
    CurrentNumOfEnemies++;
}
}

public void OnEnemyDeath()
{
  CurrentNumOfEnemies--;
/*     
if (CurrentNumOfEnemies < 5)
 {
     // You killed everyone, change scene: 
     LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
 }
 */
KilledEnemies++;

if (Time.timer > 0 && KilledEnemies >= EnemiesToNextLevel)
{
    LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
}   
}
}
```

### Modified Timer script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
 {
public Text TimerText;
public float MainTime;
public static float timer;
public  bool CanCount = true;
public  bool OnlyOnce = false;

void Start()
{
timer = MainTime; //Timer is gonna be equal to what we set MainTime in the     inspector 
}

void Update()
{
if (timer >= 0.0f && CanCount)
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;//The timer will count down in delta time based on the seconds we have 
    TimerText.text = timer.ToString("F");//Converting Timer into a string value 
}

//This means that when the timer reaches zero and OnlyOnce is equal to false 
else if (timer <= 0.0f && !OnlyOnce) //If the timer goes below 0 and OnlyOnce is not equal to flase 
{

    CanCount = false; //CanCount is equal to false so we are not counting down anymore since it's not greater than zero and we can't count anymore
    OnlyOnce = true; //This is goning to be done once when it reaches it 
    TimerText.text = "0.00"; //Setting the UI to 0 
    timer = 0.0f; //Setting the timer to 0
    if(Time.timer == 0.0f && EnemySpawner.Instance.KilledEnemies != EnemySpawner.Instance.EnemiesToNextLevel)
    {
    LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    }
        }

    }
}
```

PS: Code can be improved. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: It did take me to the losing scene when the timer ran out so that worked thank you very much. However now I need it to take me to the win scene when the player does kill the required amount of enemies before the timer runs out. Do you think you can help me on this as well ?

Comment: Done :) Edited the enemyspawner script.

Comment: Thank you so much x

Answer (score 0):

In the update function of the timer

```
void Update()
{
if (timer >= 0.0f && CanCount)
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;//The timer will count down in delta time based on the seconds we have 
    TimerText.text = timer.ToString("F");//Converting Timer into a string value 
}

//This means that when the timer reaches zero and OnlyOnce is equal to false 
else if (timer <= 0.0f && !OnlyOnce) //If the timer goes below 0 and OnlyOnce is not equal to flase 
{

    CanCount = false; //CanCount is equal to false so we are not counting down anymore since it's not greater than zero and we can't count anymore
    OnlyOnce = true; //This is goning to be done once when it reaches it 
    TimerText.text = "0.00"; //Setting the UI to 0 
    timer = 0.0f; //Setting the timer to 0
    EnemySpawner.timeIsZero = true;
}

}
}
```

then in your EnemySpawner script add a public static boolean timeIsZero = false; on the top and then in the

```
public void OnEnemyDeath()
 {
   /*  CurrentNumOfEnemies--;
     if (CurrentNumOfEnemies < 5)
     {
         // You killed everyone, change scene: 
         LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
     }
     */

   /* KilledEnemies++;
    if (KilledEnemies >= EnemiesToNextLevel)
    {
        LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("NextLevelMenu");
    }
    */
if(timeIsZero && KilledEnemies != EnemiesToNextLevel)
{
    LaserLevelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
}


}



}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time !